# Переход от libgdx к android activity

Tags: java, android, libgdx

В приложении запускается сперва android activity. По нажатию кнопки запускается AndroidLauncher, который грузит класс на libgdx.
Нужно, чтобы по истечении некоторого времени класс на libgdx закрывался и переходил обратно к android activity, но уже другой.
Как так сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread PerehodTime = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int PerehodTime = 0; 
                    while(PerehodTime < 2000){
                        sleep(100);
                        PerehodTime = PerehodTime + 100;
                    }; //некоторое время
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainClass.this, DrugayaActivity.class); //переход
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        PerehodTime.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать на подобие Splash Screen, уроков в инете полно.
Хотя как по мне, можно использовать и Handler с таймером.